# For Loop only Looping Once js

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, var

I'm a beginner with JavaScript. I'm trying to make my work easier by writing less code, so I coded this..

```
for (counta = 0; counta < 22; counta++)
{
    window["varEnemyType1" + counta] = document.getElementById("EnemyType1" + counta).options[document.getElementById("EnemyType1" + counta).selectedIndex].text;
    window["varEnemyType2" + counta] = document.getElementById("EnemyType2" + counta).options[document.getElementById("EnemyType2" + counta).selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Before this I have set global vars e.g. (`var varEnemyType11 = "";`)
I'm going though all vars with 'counta' and then assigning a value.

In my troubleshooting I found out the `for` loop is only counting '0' and nothing after even the rest of the function. Why is that?

Comment: It loops only once because at `counta === 0` it throws an error. Maybe there is no element with id `EnemyType10` on your page?

Comment: Your browser has *development tools* that you can access via Ctrl+Shift+I (Cmd+Shift+I on a Mac) and/or F12. Those will be showing you useful information.

Comment: Please show HTML code too. And fix this line (add `var` keyword) `for (var counta = 0; counta < 22; counta++)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note the formatting and typo corrections I've made in your question. Taking the time to use proper capitalization, punctuation, using code blocks without unnecessary indentation, etc., are all ways to improve your chances of getting good answers. Also note that Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) are for **runnable** examples. Yours was not, so just a code block (the `{}` toolbar button) was the way to go (of course, creating a runnable [mcve] is very well-received).

Comment: Re @semanser's point: By not declaring the variable, you've made it an *implicit global*. See [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(on my blog)*.

Comment: Do not create variable names dynamically like this as if it were AWK or something. That's what arrays are for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. I know that will be better to use `let` keyword, but I don't think that TC something know about running ES6 code (with Babel etc) :)

Comment: Ok thank you guys for the tips, will look at my code again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need use var in the  counta declaration for example:

```
   for ( var counta = 0; counta < 22; counta++ ){
       //your code......
   }
```

Regards

Answer (score -2):

Your loop is "ok", but you need to catch exceptions to tell if that's why it's not getting past the first one:

```
for ( var counta = 0; counta < 22; counta++ )
{
    try
    {
        window["varEnemyType1" + counta] = document.getElementById("EnemyType1" + counta).options[document.getElementById("EnemyType1" + counta).selectedIndex].text;
        window["varEnemyType2" + counta] = document.getElementById("EnemyType2" + counta).options[document.getElementById("EnemyType2" + counta).selectedIndex].text;
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        //You should be doing this, but you might not know how to get to the console
        console.log( ex );

        alert( ex );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down votes? My answer will help him discover why his loop isn't working

Comment: I think he can discover why his loop isn't working by opening development tools and not by writing new code.

Comment: Thanks Don, didn't know that, I'll look into it